# Get rid of type assertion when checking if value is part of union

Tags: typescript, static-typing

I have a union type which is partially based on an array - which I also want to use to check values at run-time. However, TypeScript forces me to use a type-assertion here.
Consider the code below:

```
const Pets = ["dog", "cat"] as const
type Pet = typeof Pets[number]

type Animal = Pet | "tiger"

function checkDanger(animal: Animal) {
  if (Pets.includes(animal as Pet)) {
        return "not dangerous"
    }
    return "very dangerous"
}
```

The problem is the `as Pet` part.

If I leave that out, I'll get: `Argument of type 'Animal' is not assignable to parameter of type '"dog" | "cat"'. Type '"tiger"' is not assignable to type '"dog" | "cat"'.`

However, in a more complex real-world situation, that assertion might have effects I'd like to avoid. Is there a way to do such a thing without an assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with `includes`, see [issues/26255](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255).

However, there is a workaround. You can create a custom `curried` [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
const inTuple = <Tuple extends string[]>(
    tuple: readonly [...Tuple]) => (elem: string
    ): elem is Tuple[number] =>
        tuple.includes(elem)

// (elem: string) => elem is "dog" | "cat"
const inPets = inTuple(Pets)
```

Lets try it:

```js
const Pets = ["dog", "cat"] as const
type Pet = typeof Pets[number]

type Animal = Pet | "tiger"

const inTuple = <Tuple extends string[]>(
    tuple: readonly [...Tuple]) => (elem: string
    ): elem is Tuple[number] =>
        tuple.includes(elem)

// (elem: string) => elem is "dog" | "cat"
const inPets = inTuple(Pets)

function checkDanger(animal: Animal) {
    if (inPets(animal)) {
        animal // "dog" | "cat"
        return "not dangerous"
    }
    return "very dangerous"
}
```

Since you have a conditional statement, I assume this function can be overloaded in order to narrow return type:

```js
const Pets = ["dog", "cat"] as const
type Pet = typeof Pets[number]

type Animal = Pet | "tiger"

const inTuple = <Tuple extends string[]>(
    tuple: readonly [...Tuple]) => (elem: string
    ): elem is Tuple[number] =>
        tuple.includes(elem)

// (elem: string) => elem is "dog" | "cat"
const inPets = inTuple(Pets)


function checkDanger(animal: Pet): "not dangerous"
function checkDanger(animal: Animal): "very dangerous"
function checkDanger(animal: string) {
    if (inPets(animal)) {
        animal // "dog" | "cat"
        return "not dangerous"
    }
    return "very dangerous"
}

const result = checkDanger('tiger') // very dangerous
const result2 = checkDanger('cat') // not dangerous
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG6Kkm)
The order of overload signatures matter.

As you might have noticed, there are no type assertions in my code.

`inTuple` typeguard works, because `tuple` is treated as an array of strings inside function body. It means that this operation is allowed, since `tuple[number]` and `elem` are assignable to each other.

```js
const inTuple = <Tuple extends string[]>(
    tuple: readonly [...Tuple]) =>
    (elem: string): elem is Tuple[number] => {
        tuple[2] = elem // ok
        elem = tuple[3] // ok
        return tuple.includes(elem)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is a limitation of the typescript compiler. However, instead of writing in thousand functions same line of `animal as Pet` you can utilize Type Guards as follows

```
function isPet(something: Pet | Animal) : something is Pet {
    return Pets.includes(something as Pet)
} 

function checkDanger(animal: Animal) {
    if (isPet(animal)) {
        return "not dangerous"
    }
    return "very dangerous"
}
```

This approach is more applicable since if you will rename your type definition name, it will be easier to refactor your code.

Still, if you declare a read-only array, you lose the flexibility, and type assertion has to be performed.